# How does Google Docs store documents (on the backend)?

Tags: file-format, google-docs

I half imagine there being these great .docs in the sky... but another part of me doubts that my documents are even being stored in anything we'd traditionally call a "file." Does Google have its own document format? I feel like it must. Some branch of some existing format like ODF, maybe? Any idea what it's like, what's special about it (if anything), and/or why it is the way it is?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, Google Docs originally generated [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTF) files. Now, however, with the recent push of HTML5 and integration of the [ContentEditable](http://html5demos.com/contenteditable) module, they may very well just store documents as plain HTML within their database.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that google definitly extracts some information for indexing from the file. For editing purposes however, I do not think the internal format will be so much different from ODF/MS-Office or other file formats. But those are only guesses, maybe someone else knows more.